# Cannot understand has_one relation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activeadmin

I have some problems understanding the `has_one` relation.

I have two models `Planning` and `Sport`. A `Planning` is concerned by one `Sport` and a `Sport` can be found in many `Planning`s. So I defined my `Planning` this way:

```
class Planning 
    ...  
    has_one :sport
    ...
end
```

And I didn't add anything in `Sport` regarding the `Planning`. 
In my mind, this would allow me to access `planning.sport` but I don't mind if I can't find `sport.plannings` (which makes no sense).

The problem is that when I try to create a new `Planning` using my `ActiveAdmin` interface, I have the following error as soon as I try to access the `plannings/new` page:

```
undefined method `planning_id' for #<Planning:0x30d8570>
```

What I understand is that it checks in `Sport` that a `planning_id` exists, but my understanding was that there was just a `sport_id` in the `Planning`, not the opposite...

What did I do wrong? Do I need to use an intermediary model? Is this jsut linked to `ActiveAdmin`?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you need is

```
class Planning 
    ...  
    belongs_to :sport
    ...
end

class Sport

   has_many: plannings
end
```

You can think of it like, whoever has the foreign key is like the child. So here planning has the foreign key of sport. So it is a child of Sport and it belongs to sport.

Comment: Wow I can't believe that was so simple... Thanks Vimsha! I was sure I had tested that. I realize I still have a lot to do to fully understand Rails' logic!